# Why isn't my input redirection working?

Tags: c, linux, input

Here's the code that I'm trying to run

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int overFlow(char* value){
  char string[8];
  strcpy(string, value);
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  char string[10];
  strcpy(string, argv[1]);
  overFlow(string);
  return 0;
}
```

with a simple text file that has this

```
hello
```

but when I execute "./program < textfile" I get a seg fault.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Your "command shell" is changing STDIN from the terminal to being the contents of "textfile".  Your program should interrogate "argc" to determine if there are arguments present... "./program < textfile" will have an argc of 1, the name of your program... "./program textfile" would have an "argc" of 2... and argv[1] will contain "textfile"....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Do you want to read a file through input redirection? or You want read it from a file, given as argument to your program. Your code btw is conflicting in how you wrote it and how you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your program with following command:

```
./program < textfile
```

You don't pass any arguments to program. So arg count is 1, and this array  : argv just has program name

And this line fails:

```
strcpy(string, argv[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers are right about the actual cause. The command you could use to call the program is this:

```
cat textfile | ./myprogram
```

What this does is first the cat command prints out the contents of textfile and the | operator puts the output of one command into the input of the next. So it then runs

```
./myprogram hello
```

You may also want to increase your buffers and look at strncpy to prevent overflows.